# Advanced Find Search Folder in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

I have to run an advanced find everyday on my org's Network Control Mailbox to run a filter against all subfolders of that inbox.

While <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is handy, I'd like an easier alternative, as the filter is the same filter everytime.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution whould be using the [Outlook Search Folders](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Search-Folder-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5). This way you'll only need to open this folder to see the results.